# Cannot pip install packages relying on updating SciPy - Get repeated wheel errors referencing compilers

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip, scipy

This started with me trying to install the pandas-profiling library, which involves an update to SciPy.  After this failed repeatedly due to wheel errors (more on this), I used SciPy to test what was going on, and found out this was failing to update, even when using "pip install -U SciPy"
Screenshots of errors below -- what is frustrating is that the log file it claims to generate in fact **never is generated and there is not a folder or file where it claims to be** and I have been through several iterations of tracking down, and in some cases having to create folders that were missing, updating 2017 build tools based on some of the errors that came up.  That could be a whole other thread, but this is where it stands now when I try to update SciPy:
[Screenshot of output part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCAX.png)

[Screenshot of output part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HooP8.png)

At this point I am immensely frustrated.  What is the fix here?  Will uninstalling all Python instances fix this?  Or is there a deeper problem?  I assumed the latter, but I have been installing things that seem to be missing and there's always something more.  What the heck is going on?  How can this be so screwed up on my machine and apparently unfixable?

Tried already:
pip install wheel
pip install meson
..and about a million iterations of installing other libraries or different flags on pip, no binary, update, etc.  Python's not supposed to be this hard to set up, right?  It wasn't before....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like it's because you have 32 bit version of python installed and you are going from version 1.4.1 to 1.9.2.

SciPy v1.4.1 has a wheel (prebuilt binary) for 32 bit windows for python 3.8

SciPy v1.9.2 only has a wheel for 64bit windows python 3.8.

So when you installed it first (v1.4.1) everything was already compiled for you and it would have installed no problem.

As there is no wheel for v1.9.2 pip is attempting to build and compile everything from source (tar.gz file).
The SciPy docs say this is a nontrivial exercise but do provide steps https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/dev/contributor/building.html

You should be able to upgrade to v1.9.1 as this has wheel for python 3.8 32 bit.

Comment: Not trivial indeed.  What a massive pain.  So this is because I have a 32-bit version of Python?  Is it instead easier to install a 64 bit?  What would be that procedure, would I need to uninstall the 32 bit versions first?  The whole point of this update was to use the pandas-profiling library, meant to reduce effort.  This seems to have massively backfired.  Apparently by inference, pandas-profiling is 64 bit only?  I sure wish the Pydata spiel I watched promoting it had made this clear.

Comment: It seems that only scipy 1.9.2 does not have a 32bit windows wheel. In the short term
`pip install -U SciPy==1.9.1` should update fine for you. Then `pip install pandas-profiling scipy==1.9.1` should ensure it uses the version you have installed. In the longer term consider using a virtual environment for projects as installing into your global python can cause more dependency conflicts going forward.